# How to do covariance test for our dataset?

Tags: r, covariance

```
carData=mtcars[,c("am","mpg","hp")]
carData
```

This was the example from RStudio that we used as an example to do covariance test, what should I plug in to "mtcars" in this code for my own dataset?

I tried inserting the name of my csv file dataset instead of "mtcars" but that didn't work and i got an error of "Error: object 'Prestige_New' not found"

Comment: You need to read the csv file, i.e. `carData <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")`

Comment: Hi, yes i read the csv file, Still getting this error :
> data<-read.csv("Prestige_New.csv")
> Data<-Prestige_New[,c("type","prestige","income")]
Error: object 'Prestige_New' not found

Comment: You should be using `data[, c("type","prestige","income")]`  as data is the object created